# Render Pokemon double-type weaknesses/resistances in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I'm creating a small component that takes the type(s) of a Pokemon stored in the state (pokemonState.types) as an array of objects for each type, then compare the type(s) to a JSON file containing all the weaknesses/resistances (see below).

**Here is what the json looks like:**

```
    "dragon": {
         "half": ["electric", "fire", "grass", "water"],
         "double": ["dragon", "ice", "fairy"],
         "zero": []
     },
     "ground": {
          "half": ["poison", "rock"],
          "double": ["grass", "ice", "water"],
          "zero": ["electric"]
      },
```

However, I'm **struggling a lot to code the render part for Pokemon with double-types**. Here is a picture similar to what I want to render (exactly like pokemon websites pretty much):

[image]

Note that if both types have a weakness in common, the multiplier displayed is x4 instead of x2. If both types have a resistance in common the multiplier is 0.25 instead of 0.

**Here is my code so far that works fine for single-type Pokemon:**

```
 const PokemonChart = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
      const listWeaknesses = pokemonState.types.map((item) =>
        types_data[item.type.name].double.map((el) => (
          <p className={`types ${el}`} key={el}>
            {el}
          </p>
        ))
      );
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Type Effectiveness</h1>
          {listWeaknesses}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

My first issue, is that when **two types share a weakness, this weakness will be listed twice**. I tried to merge both type's data together into an array to make it easier, but as they're rendered one after the other it didn't work.

(see below an example with Dragon/Ground type pokemon).

[image: example with Dragon/Ground type pokemon]

**My question**: How can I get rid of duplicates types, but also keep track of them, so that I can render different multipliers. Example: If "ice x2" is rendered twice, returns one "ice x4" instead.

Comment: Can you clarify what the data would look like for a "double type" pokemon? Based on what I remember from last night, I'm assuming that you're talking about a scenario in which your pokemonState is an array containing two types, like `const pokemonState ={types: [{type:{name: "electric"}}, {type:{name: "fire"}}]};`, is that correct? And so in that scenario, if both of those types share a common strength or weakness, that has a multiplier effect?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaCraven! Good to see you around haha, your help is much appreciated. I'm struggling a lot more than expected with this component.

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to post an actual example of the pokemonState? In particular, an example of the pokemonState that would be considered a double type?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how pokemonState.type looks like for a double-type pokemon: [Link of double type output](https://i.imgur.com/HVI1VqX.png)

Comment: One more question: if a pokemon is a double type, does the multiplier effect impact all scenarios? So not only does double + double = 4x, but half plus double = 1x? and half plus half = .25x, etc?

Comment: Yes, a normal resistance is x0.5 and a normal weakness is x2. If both types share a common strength the attack is multiplied by 0.25; if they share a common weakness it's x4.

Comment: Yes you're right. let's say if the 1st type has a weakness against the "water" type and the 2nd type has a resistance against "water" type, then damage multiplier is x1.

Comment: Please format your JSON correctly, it's hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go :)

```js
const e = React.createElement;
const getPokemon = () => {
    return (
        {   "name": "bulbasaur",
            "types": [
                {
                    "slot": 1,
                    "type": {
                        "name": "grass",
                        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "slot": 2,
                    "type": {
                        "name": "poison",
                        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "weight": 69
        }
    );
}
const pokemonState = getPokemon();

let types_data = {
    "grass": {
        "attack": {
            "double": ["ground", "rock", "water"],
            "half": ["flying", "poison", "bug", "steel", "fire", "grass", "dragon" ],
            "zero": []
        },
        "defense": {
            "half": ["ground", "water", "grass", "electric"],
            "double": ["flying", "poison", "bug", "fire", "ice"],
            "zero": []
        }
    },
    "poison": {
        "attack": {
            "double": ["grass", "fairy"],
            "half": ["poison", "ground", "rock", "fairy"],
            "zero": ["steel"]
        },
        "defense": {
            "half": ["fighting", "poison", "bug", "grass", "fairy"],
            "double": ["ground", "psychic"],
            "zero": []
        }
    }
};

const PokemonTypeChart = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonState)) {
        const allTypes = Object.entries(types_data);
        const pokemonType = allTypes.map(([key, value]) => {
            return (pokemonState.types.map((el) => {
                if (el.type.name === key) {
                    return (
                        <p key="{el.type.name}">{el.type.name}</p>
                    );
                }
            }));
        });


        let weaknesses = {};
        pokemonState.types.forEach(item =>{
            let defense = types_data[item.type.name].defense;
            Object.entries(defense).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                switch(key){
                    case('double'):
                        value.forEach(i => {weaknesses[i] ? weaknesses[i] *= 2 : weaknesses[i] = 2});
                        break;
                    case('half'):
                        value.forEach(i => {weaknesses[i] ? weaknesses[i] *= .5 : weaknesses[i] = .5});
                        break;
                    case('zero'):
                        value.forEach(i => {weaknesses[i] = 0});
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

        const weaknessDisplay = [];
        Object.entries(weaknesses).forEach(([key, value]) =>
        {
            weaknessDisplay.push(<li key={key}>{key} - {value}x</li>);
        });
              return (
            <div>
                <h1>{pokemonState.name}</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Pokemon Type</h2>
                {pokemonType}
                <hr />
                <h2>Weaknesses</h2>
                {weaknessDisplay}

            </div>
        );
    }};


const domContainer = document.querySelector('#pokemon');
ReactDOM.render(e(PokemonTypeChart), domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="pokemon"></div>
```

Comment: I don't have time to explain the code at the moment, so if you have questions, just ask!

Comment: Awesome, I am also learning from this. Got an upvote from me. @Joshua: any chance you can help with the following as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946807/how-to-fetch-only-items-from-json-if-certain-object-value-is-there

Comment: Hi Joshua, this is exactly the kind of output I was looking for. No questions, I spent the last hour studying it, it's very clear now. Thank you so much for help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked out for you!